# Double Slit Experiment doubts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Well, I've been reading about this experiment and watched some videos, I'm not a Physicist, and also don't know much about this kind of stuff. But that experiment made me very curious.

For what I understood, you would shoot a particle through the double slits and check the pattern on the display screen on the other side. 
So, first,

- how are those particles thrown, I mean, they are not Aimed?
- And if you throw one at a time with the exact same position and angle, shouldn't it go always the same path?

Sorry if what I'm asking is absurd, but

- what would happen if I AIM my particle through one of the slits, keeping the other open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of microscopic physics.

Let's start with the issue of aiming. The bottom line is that you can't really aim, because the particles are so light that they naturally disperse in flight. It's really a wave mechanics phenomena but let's not go too deep into it. You can however observe the same phenomena if you shine light through a small slit. The smaller you make the slit, the hared it is to aim the light.

As for how the particles are thrown, this can be quite dependant on the particular experiment. However, the particles are typically accelerated in some electric field to the speeds desired. This also partly answers why aiming is hard, since the acceleration process is a lot like firing a shotgun. You just spray particles everywhere.

Comment: _you can't really aim._  You can do the double-slit experiment with a laser.  Are you saying you can't aim a laser?  Of course you can!  And, you can use lenses to focus the beam down to a tiny spot, or you can use lenses to spread it out.  If you focus it so that it illuminates only one slit, then you will get a smooth diffraction pattern.  If you spread it enough to illuminate both slits, then you will see interference bands.  You can do the same with a coherent beam of charged particles (e.g., electrons) and magnetic or electrostatic "lenses".

Comment: @jameslarge Yes I was oversimplifying. But it is a matter of length-scales. You can aim down to scales on par with the wave-length but not smaller.

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics, a physical system is described by a mathematical doodad that I will call the wave function (sometimes you would use other mathematical doodads) that is spread out across some region of space. The system is not in one specific place, it is at all of the regions where the wave function is non-zero. And the probability of seeing the particle in a particular region is related to the size of the wave function in that region. Measuring where a system is means putting detectors in various places and waiting to see if they go off. A particle is roughly the simplest kind of wave function that can set off a detector.

There are limits to how much a wave function can be concentrated in position and momentum. If you change the wave function so that it has a very narrow peak in position, then it will be more spread out in momentum and vice versa. The particle moves not by going down a single path, but rather by the wave function going down all of the possible paths. As a result, you can't make the particle go down a single path. In cases where you see something go down a single path, that is a result of looking at it on a large scale where the spread of the wave function is small compared to the scale you're looking at.

Now, you could aim a particle at a single slit in the sense that if the slits are far enough apart, you could aim a the wave function so that it is high at one slit and negligible at the other. In that case, you would see the pattern that results from the wave function going down all of the paths allowed by that slit. This is commonly called a diffraction pattern.